# Manifest merger failed after adding PlayServices library

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-manifest, google-play-services

I added

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

to "dependencies" block in by build.gradle, and after that gradle throws Error when I try to sync project:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

MinSdk version I using is 8, target, compile and build tools is 19.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

What does that error means and how to solve it? I using Intellij Idea as IDE.
Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that "com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71" requires minSdk at least 9.

Changing minSdk value solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can go at gradle.build
and declare the minsdk as

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.gpstracker"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```